# Problem using LaunchedEffect scope in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have two LaunchedEffect scopes like this :

```
  LaunchedEffect(key1 = mainViewModel.myvlue.value){
                            mainViewModel.updatemyvalue(1f)
                            

                    }




  LaunchedEffect(key1 = mainViewModel.myvlue.value){
                            mainViewModel.updatemyvalue(0f)
                            

                    }
```

Both are implemented inside this method :

```
@Composable
fun TabContent( pagerState: PagerState,count:Int,mainViewModel: MainViewModel) {
    

        HorizontalPager(state = pagerState, count = count) { index ->
            when (index) {
                0 -> {
                    LaunchedEffect(key1 = mainViewModel.myvlue.value){
                            mainViewModel.updatemyvalue(1f)
                            

                    }

                    SecondScreen(mainViewModel)
                }

                1 -> {
                    LaunchedEffect(key1 = mainViewModel.myvalue.value) {

                            mainViewModel.updatemyvalue(0f)
                        

                    }

                    firstScreen(mainViewModel)


                }

            }

        }
    }
```

The problem is that when one of these scopes launches, second one will be automatically called .

I  know this is normal that when the key1 value changes scopes will be relaunched . but I
just want them to be called separately when I navigate to their respective page inside HorizontalPager.

As you can see above, they will be called simultaneously when one of the executes.

what should I do ?

Comment: It is not clear why you should use a side effect in this way clicking a button.

Comment: That was wrong. I've edited the post.

Comment: Why not just remove the LaunchedEffects, are they needed for some reason?

Comment: Compose code needs to be side effect free. Because Composables can run at any time, in parallel or not at all. If I do not use this block,  My code is not guaranteed to be executed at all.  More info : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#parallel

Comment: Have you tried moving LaunchedEffects out of the HorizontalPager, then use a boolean to determine which to use.  LaunchedEffect(yourBoolean){ ...,   set the boolean to true or false in your HorizontalPager and it should trigger the LaunchedEffect when true or when false for the second Launched Effect

Comment: In that way , I should also set boolean to true or false inside another LaunchedEffect scope ,Because this is the composable function . This will make it complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the current index below in the way I posted in the attachment

Please test

```
// Page change callback
LaunchedEffect(pagerState) {
    snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }.collect { page ->
        when (page) {
            0 -> viewModel.updatemyvalue() // First page
            1 -> // Second page
            else -> // Other pages
        }
    }
}
```